# BindingExpressionBase is null in custom MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, markup-extensions

I have a `CustomMarkupExtension` class. The Binding is working (!= null), but the `BindingExpressionBase` is always `null`.

Can someone explain me why? I need to get the `BindingExpressionBase` to call the `UpdateTarget()` method.

#### C# Code

```
public class CustomMarkupExtension : MarkupExtension
{

    public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Binding == null) return null;

        BindingExpressionBase expression = Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) as BindingExpressionBase;
        if (expression != null)
        {
            expression.UpdateTarget();
        }
        return expression;
    }
}
```

#### XAML Code

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Alarms, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Extensions:CustomMarkupExtension Binding={Binding Number}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider)` is a `BindingExpressionBase`? What does the debugger shows?

Comment: I have extended the XAML example. I hope not to have messed up something. Debug of `Binding` or `serviceProvider`?

Comment: I've come a little farther. If I use this `MarkupExtension` on the `ItemsSource` everything works like expected. But I need it on the items..

Comment: What type does the debugger shows if you put a breakpoint on it? store the result first `var obj = Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);`

Comment: Type of "obj" is `Binding`. The `TargetObject` property of "serviceProvider" is `{System.Windows.SharedDp}` and the `TargetProperty` is `{Text}`.

Comment: It might happen when binding actually fails (such as not existing `Number` property). What happens if you just do `Text={Binding Number}` instead, does that work correctly?

Comment: @Evk that work's like expected. I don't have any BindingErrors in on my ConsoleOutput. I have a second separate `DataGridTemplateColumn` where just `Text={Binding Number}` is used for controlling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is you are using markup extension inside a template (`DataTemplate` in this case). When your markup extension is parsed by xaml parser - control is not yet created and there is no target for a binding. In such case you should return your markup extension itself (`return this`). If you do it - it will be applied again each time control is created using that template.

Built-in `Binding` is of course follows this pattern too, that is why it returns itself (`Binding`) and not `BindingExpression` when target object is not yet available. So to fix, you have to do this:

```
public class CustomMarkupExtension : MarkupExtension
{

    public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        if (Binding == null) return null;

        var result = Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        var expression = result as BindingExpressionBase;
        if (expression != null) {
            expression.UpdateTarget();
            return expression;
        }
        // no expression - return self to apply it again later
        return this;            
    }
}
```

If you will create custom markup extension which does not rely on other extension (like `Binding` in this case), you can check if you have target by doing this:

```
var target = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
bool hasTarget = target.TargetObject is DependencyObject;
```

Comment: Ah thank you! As you have already noticed, I refer to your example (http://stackoverflow.com/a/44033806/6229375).

Comment: @DominicJonas yes I've just updated it with this information, didn't know it myself and just discovered.

Comment: Where did you get this information? Was looking myself without any success.

Comment: I noticed that target object is strange "SharedDp" object, then found this question on msdn: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9ead3d5-a4e4-4f9c-b507-b7a7d530c6a9/gaining-access-to-target-object-instead-of-shareddp-in-custom-markupextensions-providevalue-method?forum=wpf